# UIAutomation not working with Distribution type of IPA

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios-ui-automation

I am trying to automate the app using `UIAutomation`. It works only with IPA built with development provisioning profile. It stucks in case of IPA built with `distribution provisioning profile` whether it is adhoc or app store distribution. It just launches app and then Instruments hang up with recording page and doesn't record any steps. But it is working fine in case of `development provisioning profile`. I have read this note from Instruments User Guide provided by apple

Note: For your protection, the Automation instrument enables you to process only apps that have been code signed with your provisioning profile. These apps include any copy that has been downloaded from the iTunes App Store.

Link for this Guide - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/UsingtheAutomationInstrument/UsingtheAutomationInstrument.html

According to this guide, I can automate the app also that has been downloaded from app store also if I have signed it with my provisioning profile. I have all provisioning profiles and certificates of my app but still not able to automate the app.

I have tried all things but it is not working whether there is mistake in documentation or I am doing something wrong..

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the note on the page OP linked to, it says: 
Note: The Automation instrument only works with apps that have been code signed with a development provisioning profile. Apps signed with a distribution provisioning profile can not be automated with the UI Automation programming interface.

You can only test on Apps that are code signed with a development profile. Once an app is signed for distribution, it can only be used by the App Store, as noted [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2285/_index.html).

Answer (score 0):

I've been dealing with a similar problem as of late.

- We have Jenkins build our ipas, and the usual workflow is to copy them to my machine and run the UI automation.
- All had been working for me just fine.  However, we changed provisioning profiles recently.
- I verified that my UDIDs were on this provisioning profile, and that I had copied this latest and greatest provisioning profile both to my device and my computer.

When I start the UI Automation now (just like the above user) app is launched, no steps are recorded.  Adding a `-v` for verbosity didn't seem to help either.

When I build locally from our latest trunk (same code), then archive to an ipa, UI automation runs fine.
It looks like the ipa from our Jenkins server is not matching up with what I have.  However, talking to development, all looks like things should be working.

There must be something else I'm missing here.

Comment: This sounds like the basis for a new question, rather than an answer to the question posed. I'd recommend asking a new question based on this, and linking back to this one if necessary.

Comment: Yes you are right. When you build locally on device, it builds with development provisioning profile. But jenkins build is built with distribution provisioning profile. And you can't run automation on distribution build